# is IIS smooth streaming work with html5 player

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

Is there anyway to make IIS smooth streaming work with html5 player. if not, what is recommended streaming server for that (I'm using ASP.Net for my web pages)?  wowza, red5 or fms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diffrent browsers unfortunately support different video standards, but the industry *seems to be* moving towards MPEG-DASH as an open standard that most browsers will support.

Most streaming servers will either support this or have a roadmap story to support it.

You need a HTML5 Javascript video player generally to allow it playback on most browsers at this time - BitDash is a good example (https://www.dash-player.com).

Comment: what is recommended streaming server ?

Comment: It is apparently possible to create DASH content on IIS (http://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/dash-with-iis/) but your wider question about recommended streaming server is harder to answer as personal opinion etc will come into it. I think it is safe to day that Wowza (http://www.wowza.com) is a common choice. Note that you can host your videos separately from the rest of your site, either on your own streaming server like Wowza or using an ad free, unbranded video hosting service like Brightcove, Ooyala etc (https://www.brightcove.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, a perfectly good IIS Smooth Streaming server is built into windows since windows 7 and server 2008.

IIS 7 and up will work just fine, windows 7, 8 and 10 will support up to 10 simultaneous users and the server platforms are limited by the amount of bandwidth you got.

A good example of this setup is http://www.tvbydemand.com

The player is free and works on all browsers for the pc, Iphones and all settop boxes like the Roku etc. Android does not support it except on the settop boxes.

We have been hearing about the standardization of mpeg-dash now for 10 years and have yet to see it. Google and Microsoft have been battling over different formats for the last 5 years. Mpeg-Dash is supported but so is HLS and HLS is much more popular. And IIS Smooth Streaming is still supported on the Azure platform by microsoft as well as windows 10 and server 2016.

Wowza is a great media server platform if you have a beefy server and alot of cash to pay for the software and then the yearly maintenance/upgrade fees.

Eitherway though, the only rendering software that supports todays codecs is soreson squeeze and that is pricey, but it will render IIS, HLS, mpeg-dash and all the container formats known and usefull to mankind. it is pricey but worth it.

anyway you can download a sample player by googleing "sample IIS smooth streaming player", it will end .xap

or you can download it from http://www.tvbydemand.com/finished.xap